# Store the name of the 2nd last directory of the ls -ltr| tail -2 output in a variable

Tags: linux

Example:

```
$ ls -ltr | tail -2
drwxr-xr-x 7 abl jb 1256 May  7 12:55 sp1
drwxr-xr-x 2 abl jb 1345 May  7 12:57 sp2
```

The above out shows two directories sp1 and sp2. I want to store the directory name sp1(2nd last modified directory) in a variable.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it you want to get only the 'sp1' directory from the output.

It can be done like this:

```
ls -ltr | tail -2 | awk '{print $9}' | sed -n 1p
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is vague so I'm guessing you want to print the last two lines of `ls -ltr` into a file `output.txt`

here is one way of doing it:

```
ls -ltr | tail -n 2 | tee output.txt
```

Comment: Not exactly, the last two lines of the output shows the directory name sp1 and sp2. I want the directory name name sp1 (which is the second last modified directory ) to be stored in a variable.